# systemd pick up changes to service unit configuration

Tags: systemd

I am learning more about systemd
which command correctly picks up changes to a service unit configuration made under systemd ?

```
systemctl daemon-restart
systemctl reboot 
systemctl daemon-reload 
systemctl daemon-reexec
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Is the one you want to use. It will reload the systemd manager configuration. This will rerun all generators, reload all unit files, and recreate the entire dependency tree.

```
systemctl daemon-reexec
```

Will reexecute the systemd manager. This will serialize the manager state, reexecute the process and deserialize the state again. This command is of little use except for debugging and package upgrades. Sometimes, it might be helpful as a heavy-weight `daemon-reload`.

```
systemctl reboot
```

Will reboot the system and as a result, changes to services configuration will be picked up after the reboot.

<s>`systemctl daemon-restart`</s>

Will not work. `daemon-restart` is not a valid argument for `systemctl`